# two web projects sharing same base source code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, web

I am creating a project that has two flavors 
one for enterprises and one for families .
the deferences are simple really  : changed labels(property) , changed colors(CSS) , a few deleted features...

i don't want to start a new project and copy the whole enterprise to the family version because that would mean that each bug must be solve in both .

technology used :JSF,Jquery,Hibernate and eclipse as an IDE also I am deploying to Jboss.

i dont know where to start but i have the following thoughts:
solution attempt 1 :
along time ago when i used to develop J2me application on netbeans we used to have something called configurations where we can choose to include deferent segments of the code depending on the configuration(device) so we would end up having multiple executable files.

solution attempt 2:choose which code is common and move it to a separate location and include it in both projects (this would be painful to implement and also i need to replicate some fixes some times)

is there any good solution to this issue ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a repository (git, svn) - create a branch for each of the versions, and then when you fix something on one of the versions, merge it to the second. With git you can have a local repo just for your own on local machine, and it's really simple to set up.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , although i was looking for other solution anyway for my case i created a global variable to switch between the two builds, and for the messages we will need to pick the right messages file before deployment